# Convert elements in a dataframe from strings to floats

Tags: python, pandas, jupyter-notebook

[Image of my data frame](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ExNyd.png)
I am doing some data analysis in Python Jupyter Notebooks.

I know that this question has been asked before but I cannot find the solution that works in this case.

I have a data frame (CALLED DATA) with 3 columns; see link above.

Note: the data.intermediary could contain more than one waypoint for each row. data.start and data.end have only 1 pair of coordinates for each row.

When looking at the data types of the rows and columns, I find that:

```
data.dtypes

start           object
intermediary    object
end             object
dtype: object
```

When I inspect the individual elements;

```
data.iloc[0,0]
> "('24.957055', ' 114.740156')"

type(data.iloc[0,0])

> str
```

All fine so far. However, I need to use these coordinates to give to the Google maps API and they need to be in float formats.

**How can I convert all these pairs of coordinates in each of the 3 columns from strings to floats?**

I have tried;

```
data.iloc[0,0].astype(float)
> AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'astype'

x = data.iloc[1,2]
type(x)  
> str
```

and then:

```
float(x) 
> ValueError: could not convert string to float: "('24.8913208', '114.5740475')"

pd.to_numeric(data.iloc[0,0])
> ValueError: Unable to parse string "('54.957055', ' -7.740156')" at position 0
```

My ideal output:

```
start, intermediary, end
0   24.957055,114.740156    39.956915136264,-6.753690062122  34.957055,114.740156
```

where these pairs of coordinates are all pairs of floats

Can someone please point out my errors?

Comment: Why do some of your columns have apostrophes in the middle

Comment: I saved the data frame to a CSV in one notebook and I was presented with the apostrophes when I read in that CSV in another notebook

Comment: No, I'm asking why your desired output has apostrophes

Comment: Apologies, typo. Fixed now

Comment: Can you add an entry of your CSV file

Comment: You need to show an example of what you mean by intermediary having multiple waypoints

Comment: Hi Murray, welcome on SO. I hope you're going to find an answer for your question. It is a good idea to read something about [How to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and produce a [mcve](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) [mcve2](http://matthewrocklin.com/blog/work/2018/02/28/minimal-bug-reports)

Comment: I have updated the question with an image to help clarify what I am asking

Answer (score -2):

Since you have not given the format of intermediary column if more than one waypoint is there, I am giving solution for single waypoint.

You basically have a tuple represented as a string in each cell value. So you need to remove the "extra string" part and convert it into tuple of floats. Fortunately, pandas has a function called `applymap` in which you can pass your custom function and it will apply to whole dataframe.

```
>>> import re, ast
>>> # My custom function
>>> def convert_to_float(tup):
        tup = re.sub(r"\'|\s+", '', tup)
        tup = ast.literal_eval(tup)
        return tup

>>> df = df.applymap(convert_to_float)
>>> df.iloc[0,0]
(34.957055, 114.740156)
>>> type(df.iloc[0,0])
<class 'tuple'>
>>> type(df.iloc[0,0][0])
<class 'float'>
```

Now you can extend this custom function for more than one waypoint in your data.